# Conversion from String to int from JSON response using Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a JSON response from REST API shown below, "total_tickets": "53" which is in the form of String type but I'm trying to convert to int type to do a conditional check using Logic App if greater than 50 then..run some blocks else other blocks. how to convert it to integer to make it for in the Condition block ?

JSON REST Response is something like this

[image: JSON REST Response]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a `int` function to get integer version for a string. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#int).

And in the logic app, you could use it like the below pic shows.

[image]

Comment: did you mean int(body('Parse_JSON')?['Tickets']?['total_tickets'])

Comment: I tried this approach and getting error, I've attached above.

Comment: I tried with `int(body('Parse_JSON')?['Tickets']?['total_tickets'])`, it could work.  Your error I get when I set the wrong property name, this means there is not this parameter in your json data, so make sure the name is correct.

Comment: @ivric, any update on this, could you use the function now?